# AngularJs service returning null object to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a `service` method in my controller to return an object. I struggled a lot to figure out the exact implementation difference between a `service` and a `factory`.

According to what I learned `service` instantiates with `new` and returns `this` to the calling controller.

I am trying to accomplish the same here..calling a `service` function in controller and storing the returned object in controller's `$scope.user` variable as follows:

**controller:**

```
app.controller('LoginFormController',['$log','$scope','userAngService','userBean',function($log,$scope,userAngService,userBean){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function(val){
        userAngService.login(val);
        $scope.user = userAngService.user;   //accessing service's user variable
        //$scope.user = userAngService.user;
        console.log($scope.user);    //empty object being logged in console
    };
}]);
```

**service:**

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
    this.user = {};
    this.login = function(val){
        console.log('from angular service');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        }).success(function(data){
            user = data;
            console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
        });
    };

    return this;
}]);
```

Above in the service the `login function(val)` is changing the `user` variable defined in the service itself.

I can make the function to `return this.user` but still am getting the same result.

What changes should I make here?

And here is what I am getting in console:
[image: console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `$http` service internally on your `userAngService` service.

Its a asynchronous service call so, just return the promise object to the controller and then assign values to `$scope.user`.

**Controller**

```
    app.controller('LoginFormController',     ['$log','$scope','userAngService','userBean',function($log,$scope,userAngService,userBean){        
    $scope.login = function(val){
        userAngService.login(val).then(function(data){
            $scope.user = data;
            console.log($scope.user);                
        });         
    };
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
    this.user = {};
    this.login = function(val){
        console.log('from angular service');
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        });
    };           
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you explain a lil what exactly was wrong with my service code? as the success function was though returning the user object?

Comment: On your code, the success function will definitely return the user object to the controller but it will take some time. During this time-period the main thread will assign values to `$scope.user` (undefined) and will exit the program loop

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting here as
`$scope.login = function(val){

            userAngService.login(val);

            setTimeout(function(){
             $scope.user = userAngService.user;
             console.log($scope.user);
            },(5*1000);  
        };`

but still it is logging blank object in console.
Here I am bypassing the time it will take to update user object in `service`

Comment: on your service inside the success function, assign values to `this.user` instead of `user`

Answer (score 1):

**Service**

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
    this.user = {};
    this.login = function(val){
        console.log('from angular service');
        // here you are returning Promise
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        }).success(function(data){
            user = data;
            console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console

            return user;
        });
    };
}]);
```

The first thing is, you don't need to return anything from `service`. This is the  one of the difference from `factory`. In `factory` you need to return an object, but no need to return any object in `service`

**controller**

```
app.controller('LoginFormController',['$log','$scope','userAngService','userBean',function($log,$scope,userAngService,userBean){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function(val){
        userAngService.login(val).then(userName){
               $scope.user = userName;
               console.log($scope.user);
        };
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Here why do I need to return `user` variable? If this `user` is being changed by login function's `.success function`, and as can also be accessed as `this.user`, can;t it be accessed directly as `$scope.user = userAngService.user`??

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is logging a blank object which is correct since it is a blank object. Can you try this?

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
    var vc = this;
    vc.user = {};
    vc.login = function(val){
        console.log('from angular service');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        }).success(function(data){
            vc.user = data;
            console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
        });
    };
}]);
```

OR this...

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
    var vc = this;
    vc.user = {};
    vc.login = function(val){
        console.log('from angular service');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        }).success(function(data){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){vc.user = data;});
            console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Neither of the two worked ! :\ got same blank object following your first approach and errors following the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service needs to return an abject. This should work:

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){
this.user = {};
this.login = function(val){
    console.log('from angular service');
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
    }).success(function(data){
        user = data;
        console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
    });
};

return this; 
}]);
```

or if you want to use private and public funtions (module pattern) in javascript. Do:

```
    app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location){

var user = {};

var handleRequestData = function(data){
    user = data;
    console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
};

var login = function(val){
    console.log('from angular service');
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
    }).success(handleRequestData);
};

/* while you returning just the login function, user and handleRequestData stay private */
return {
    login: login
};

}]);
```

Comment: I have tried returning `this` also. Still the same result. I have updated it in my question also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user promise in order to get data from a service via HTTP request because what happened when your http request give response back to controller there is no handler to receive it.

Controller should be :

```
app.controller('LoginFormController',['$log','$scope','userAngService','userBean',function($log,$scope,userAngService,userBean){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function(val){
        userAngService.login(val).then(function(res){
            $scope.user = res;   
        //$scope.user = userAngService.user;
        console.log($scope.user);
        console.log(userAngService.user);
        });

    };
}]);
```

Service should be :

```
app.service('userAngService',['$http','$log','$rootScope','$location', '$q',function($http,$log,$rootScope,$location,$q){
    this.user = {};
    this.login = function(val){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        console.log('from angular service');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/messenger/webapi/messages'
        }).success(function(data){
            user = data;
            console.log(user);   //successfully logging "user" in console
            deferred.resolve(user);
        });
        return promise;
    };

    return this;
}]);
```

I have not tested this code and i think it will work for you but if not the case please let me know.